# Shell script use find command to get list of files in order of directory files first and then sub directory and so on

Tags: linux, shell, find

i am trying to get list of files in a directory and sub directories in order.
as described below.

```
#!/bin/sh
find /home/ -type f -name "*.txt" | sort -n
```

In my script, i get output like :

```
/home/1_txt.txt 
/home/1_home/1_txt.txt 
/home/2-txt.txt 
/home/2_home/1_txt.txt
```

but i need output like

```
/home/1_txt.txt 
/home/2-txt.txt 
/home/1_home/1_txt.txt 
/home/2_home/1_txt.txt
```

Comment: How is the order defined?

Comment: i need to get in directory files first then sub directory files and if sub directory contain any more directory then files from it.  as i mentioned in my desire output.

Comment: Does this work `find /home/ -type f -print0 -name "*.txt" | sort -z`?

Comment: this gives me in one line , does not give me separate line print.

Comment: That explanation should be a part of the question (you can [edit] it), the output on its own really only lets me guess.

Comment: @ronak So `find /home/ -type f -print0 -name "*.txt" | sort -z -r`?

Comment: this is giving output in reverse order.

Comment: @BenjaminW., i have edited question part.

Answer (score 0):

you want to sort them by there paths, one way is using for loop

dir=/home(or any directory that you what to search in for "*.txt" files)

in the loop instead of 10 use the maxdepth relative to the $dir (ex: if you want to search just in $dir directory and its children directories (exclusively) use 2,so the for loop because for i in {1..2}) otherwise, use the find command's manual

for i in {1..10}; do /usr/bin/find $dir -mindepth $i -maxdepth $i -type f -name "*.txt"; done

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution using for loop and find. this gives me loop through every child directory.

```
for directory in $(find "$v_parentdirectory"  -type d | sort -n);
do
    find "$directory" -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.txt" | sort -n 

done
```